# Is it possible to simulate TMenuBreak functionality with Dev Express TdxBarSubItems?

Tags: delphi, devexpress

In my application I'm dynamically adding new TdxBarSubItems based off of a SQL query. In some cases the result set is rather large so the menu fills the entire screen and sometimes has a down arrow to scroll the list.  In a previous version of the code before switching to Dev Express, I was able to add TMenuBreak objects to make the list divide into columns.  Is there a way to do this with Dev Express components?

Comment: yes there is, read the documentation...

Comment: @Dorin Duminica: Yep, that's really helpful. Why not give the answer ? I have searched too, and haven't found it.

Comment: In my view, if you need a menu break, you need to modify you UI to something more suitable to selecting from such a large data set. You probably know this already, but I'll say it anyway!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, the functionality similar to TMenuBreak is not currenlty supported by the ExpressBars.  We are planning to implement this feature in the context of the [Make it possible to split dropdown menus by columns and rows](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Issues/ViewIssue.aspx?issueid=Q105561)  suggestion.  Sorry, no solution at the moment :(.